# php Compare two text files and output NON matching records

Tags: php, match

I have two text files of data the first file has 30 lines of data and matches with 30 lines in the second text file, but in addition the first text file has two additional lines that are added as the operator uploads file to the directory I want to find the non matching lines and out put them to be used in the same script as a mailout.

I am trying to use this code, which outputs the contents of the two files to screen.

```
<?php


if ($file1 = fopen(".data1.txt", "r")) {
    while(!feof($file1)) { $textperline = fgets($file1);
         echo $textperline;
        echo "<br>";}

if ($file2 = fopen(".data.txt", "r")) {
    while(!feof($file2)) {$textperline1 = fgets($file2);
    echo $textperline1;
    echo "<br>";}

fclose($file1);
fclose($file2);
}}
 
?>
```

But it outputs the whole list of data, can anyone help listingout only NON matching lines?

[attached output of the two files from my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSqyf.png)

I want to output only lines that are in file2 but not in file1

Comment: This lacks context, we can't see what your variables $textperline and $textperline1 actually contain. Please provide a proper [mre] of your issue, including proper test data. (The test data could be just provided via string variables, if you can reproduce the problem that way.)

Comment: In addition to lacking context, it also lacks a clear design strategy. E.g. do you want find all lines that are different 1:1? Or do you want to find any line that is not present in one file versus the other? E.g. `a b c` matches 1:1 with `a b c`  if we pretend that letters are all on new lines. However `c b a` does not match 1:1 with `a b c` even though all lines match. ... That is does the order of the lines matter or not matter?

Comment: The order of the lines will remain the same, I want to output only the lines in file2 that do not appear in file1

Comment: Must be the check case sensitive? Is the order of lines important or only the content?

Comment: I mean are new lines APPENDED TO THE END of the file2?

Comment: If the two files are exactly the same except for additional lines at the end of the first file, you could just seek to a position in the first file equal to the size of the second file.

Comment: I was thinking this @Don'tPanic. On just seeking to the end pos of the smaller file in the larger file. If of course, if "order" doesn't matter.

Comment: If order doesn't really matter, you could open and read both files line by line. The moment one line doesn't match the other, *all* of the next lines are "different" in this context remaining in both files. Is this the "behavior/design strategy" you want? It seems like a flawed design goal.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to read each file into an array (one line = one element) and then use `array_diff` to compare them. Unless you have millions of lines, this approach is the easiest.

To reuse your code, this is how you can read the 2 files into two arrays

```
$list1 = [];
$list2 = [];
if ($file1 = fopen(".data1.txt", "r")) {
    while (!feof($file1)) {
        $list1[] = trim(fgets($file1));
    }
    fclose($file1);
}

if ($file2 = fopen(".data.txt", "r")) {
    while (!feof($file2)) {
        $list2[] = trim(fgets($file2));
    }
    fclose($file2);
}
```

If the files are small and you can read them in one go, you can also use a simplified syntax.

```
$list1 = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents(".data1.txt"));
$list2 = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents(".data.txt"));
```

Then, no matter which method you chose, you can compare them as follows

```
$comparison = array_diff($list2, $list1);
foreach ($comparison as $line) {
    echo $line."<br />";
}
```

This will only output the lines of the second array that are not present in the first one.

Make sure that the one with the additional lines is the first argument of `array_diff`

Answer (score 0):

**ASSUMPTION**

Both files are not huge and you can read the whole content into the memory at once. According to this, you can put following code to the top:

```php
$file1 = "./data1.txt";
$file2 = "./data2.txt";
$linesOfFile1 = file($file1);
$linesOfFile2 = file($file2);
$newLinesInFile2 = [];
```

There are a couple cases, which you did not mention in your question.

**CASE 1**

New lines are only appended to the secode file `file2`. The solution for this case is the easiest one:

```php
$numberOfRowsFile1 = count($linesOfFile1);
$numberOfRowsFile2 = count($linesOfFile1);
if($numberOfRowsFile2 > $numberOfRowsFile1)
{
    $newLinesInFile2 = array_slice($linesOfFile2, $numberOfRowsFile1);
}
```

**CASE 2**

The lines with the same content may have different position in each file. Duplicate lines within the same file are ignored.

Furthermore the case sensitivity may play a role. That's why the content of each line should be hashed to make a simpler comparison. For both case sensitive and insensitive comparison the following function is needed:

```php
function buildHashedMap($array, &$hashedMap, $caseSensitive = true)
{
    foreach($array as $line)
    {
        $line = !$caseSensitive ? strtolower($line) : $line;
        $hash = md5($line);
        $hashedMap[$hash] = $line;
    }
}
```

**Case sensitive comparison**

```php
$hashedLinesFile1 = [];
buildHashedMap($linesOfFile1, $hashedLinesFile1);

$hashedLinesFile2 = [];
buildHashedMap($linesOfFile2, $hashedLinesFile2);

$newLinesInFile2 = array_diff_key($hashedLinesFile2, $hashedLinesFile1);
```

**Case INSENSITIVE comparison**

```php
$caseSensitive = false;
$hashedLinesFile1 = [];
buildHashedMap($linesOfFile1, $hashedLinesFile1, $caseSensitive);

$hashedLinesFile2 = [];
buildHashedMap($linesOfFile2, $hashedLinesFile2, $caseSensitive);

$newLinesInFile2 = array_diff_key($hashedLinesFile2, $hashedLinesFile1);
```